# How to scroll a flowlayoutpanel while dragging?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, flowlayoutpanel

In my Windows Forms application, I'm using a FlowLayoutPanel control to display a list of items to users.  I've been able to successfully implement reordering the items in the FlowLayoutPanel by having the user drag the control to the desired position within the FlowLayoutPanel.

But I don't know how to scroll the FlowLayoutPanel when the user drags an item past the boundaries of the panel.  I've seen examples for ListView controls but those techniques don't seem to apply to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Can someone provide sample code, preferably in c#, on how to implement this functionality?

I can provide code examples of my current reordering methodology if desired.

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer.  Adding a call to the FlowLayoutPanel's ScrollControlIntoView() method at the appropriate point solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a call to the ScrollControlIntoView() method after a control has been moved.

Comment: I don't think this is technically answering the question - it's not once the control has moved, it's as you drag the item that you want it to scroll i.e. as you drag down the list. The answer from Sasi Kumar below seems to work however.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by setting the `AutoScrollPosition` property.

In the `DragOver` Event:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = flowLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```